# Sum of asymptotic notations

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

Let's consider a function $f \in \Theta(h)$ and a function $g \in \omega(h)$, what could I conclude about the sum $f + g$?

Since $f \in \Theta(h)$ I think about $f$ as if it grows just like the function $h$, and  the function $g \in \omega(h)$ as if it grows more than $h$. Given that, to me it seems to make sense that $f + g \in \omega(h)$.

Is it right or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right - just take sum in definitions inequalities.

Comment: Adding anything positive to $g$ will preserve $\in \omega(h)$.